# Build Python Wheel which contains c library (pytidylib)

Tags: python, python-wheel, python-packaging

I found a nice Python library which I would like to use to check html:

https://github.com/countergram/pytidylib

It wraps a library written in C with ctypes.

According to the docs of pytidylib you need to install the library via apt/rpm:

> You must have both HTML Tidy and PyTidyLib installed in order to use the > functionality described here.

Source: http://countergram.github.io/pytidylib/#installing-html-tidy

I would like to have a self contained wheel.

How to build a self contained wheel which does not need the html-tidy library from apt/rpm?

Answer (score 1):

1) There is no magic here - you need a machine with both `HTML Tidy` and `PyTidyLib` installed to compile the package. You can temporary install them and uninstall after you finish the process.
2) Run `pip install wheel`
3) Run `pip wheel pytidylib`
4) The wheel is created in the `./wheelhouse` directory

Comment: Sounds easy. It would be even more easy if the upstream author would do it. How can I assist the upstream author in providing self contained wheels? I use the plural, since I guess you need a wheel for each platform.

Comment: Check the https://pythonwheels.com/ ("My package is white. What can I do?"). Basically you need to build the wheel on the given platform and upload to the PyPI.

Comment: Hey @guettli, have you successfully created the wheel?